# <set> with custom struct contains duplicates

Tags: c++, struct, set, comparator, stdset

I've been learning c++. I am stuck with this problem.

I have *set* that contains a custom struct that contains two *long int*'s a & b. I have a custom comparer struct that compares the numbers and returns true if either a or b is different.

```
typedef long int li;

struct number {
    number(li a1,li b1): a(a1), b(b1) {}
    li a, b;
};

struct compare {
    bool operator() (const number &lhs, const number& rhs) const{
        return lhs.a != rhs.a || lhs.b != rhs.b;
    }
};

int main() {
    set<number, compare> nums;
    nums.insert(number(1, 2));
    nums.insert(number(1, 1));
    nums.insert(number(2, 1));
    nums.insert(number(1, 2));
    for (auto &i : nums) {
        cout << i.a << " " << i.b << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output here is

> 1 2
>
> 2 1
>
> 1 1
>
> 1 2

It has two entries of **1 2**. Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: `compare` doesn't satisfy [the requirements of strict weak ordering](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare), and therefore your program exhibits undefined behavior. Basically, the comparator should resemble a less-than comparison, not a not-equal one.

Comment: If you want to use inequality rather than less-than, you could consider `std::unordered_set`, which needs to be able to calculate a hash and compare for equality.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can someone please enlighten why I have to use lesser than one as opposed to inequality? I'm still kinda confused.

Comment: @TheAbsurd consider 7 and 9. 7<9 is true, 7>9 is false. For your comparison, they would both be true. You don't know how std::set handles ordering and detecting duplicates behind the scenes, but many sorting algorithms use "<" to do tricks you can't do with "==" when comparing things. So the end result is that the library writer only guarantees this to work if your supplied function meets the requirements specified by the interface.

Comment: @RyanP that makes sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TheAbsurd misunderstood your question, sorry. If you ask why such requirement is there answer is "you cannot sort sequence only using result of equality operator, but can using less than".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your comparison function should return whether some element is smaller than another, not whether or not they are equal. (More formally, it must define a ["Strict weak ordering"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering) on the elements of your set.)

Use something like

```
struct compare {
    bool operator() (const number &lhs, const number& rhs) const{
        return std::tie(lhs.a, lhs.b) < std::tie(rhs.a, rhs.b);
    }
};
```

If you don't care about ordering, you may want to define a suitable hash function for your type and use [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set).

To avoid future problems like this, make sure to read [the docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). They clearly explain what your [comparison function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) is supposed to do.

For reference: [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) as used above constructs tuples of references to its arguments which can then be compared lexicographically with `<`. This is an easy, generic and fast way to build some ordering for collections of less-than-comparable stuff.

Comment: @TheAbsurd link to `std::tie` docs: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie If that seems to weird to you, a simple `if` construct like in the other answer is fine too for simple cases like this.

Comment: Uh.. your comparator must define a strict weak ordering of less-than, not greater-than.  Otherwise you're setting up a set to contain items in their reverse order.  (Your code is doing this, but the first sentence claims "greater than")

Comment: *"Otherwise you're setting up a set to contain items in their reverse order."* That depends on the order you want (and technically my first sentence was correct either way, though maybe somewhat misleading). :) Edited to make it clearer, thanks. @AndreKostur

Answer (score 5):

Your comparison function needs to meet strict/weak ordering requirements.

(I actually prefer the answer using `std::tie`, but this may be more illustrative for newcomers)

```
bool compare(const number& lhs, const number& rhs)
{
   if(lhs.a < rhs.a)
      return true;
   else if(lhs.a > rhs.a)
      return false;
   else
      return lhs.b < rhs.b;
}
```

Comment: you do not need `else` when `return` is involved

Comment: @Slava: You don't - but I think it is more elegant to put it in.  You are considering all cases of the elif chain.

Comment: I actually prefer this one.  Constructing a tuple with std::tie seems overkill.

Comment: @MartinBonner I think completely opposite, I think code would be more readable without all elses

Comment: The `std::tie` answer scales more easily than this one (when more than 2 numbers are involved)

Comment: Why not just `if(lhs.a == rhs.a) return lhs.b<rhs.b; else return lhs.a<rhs.a;`?

Comment: No reason why not, just trying to be as explicit as possible.

Comment: @MartinBonner I like `std::tie` because it's *really* hard to screw it up. But for this simple case, `if`s are fine too of course.

Comment: @RyanP express `operator<` only through `operator<` of object's components is more generic (actually code here unnecessarily uses `operator>` as well)

Comment: Thank for the answer. It works perfectly. But can someone please enlighten why I have to use this one as opposed to inequality?

Comment: @Slava Agreed, but I feel like the hard coded true and false obfuscates the concept that you really want to return the result of lhs<rhs for the first position where they aren't equal (or the last position...).

Comment: @TheAbsurd because that stated in documentation as requirement

Comment: @Slava if you don't want to use `>`, just replace `lhs.a > rhs.a` with `rhs.a < lhs.a`.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks, I almost broke my head and prepared to open a question "how to replace > with <" on SO. And it is not a question what I want, I just said it would be more generic to use only one operator.